# Recognize phone number when digits and written nubers altogether

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a patter that would recognize：

```
"+89 one5zero 77three3“ 
”+eight2three 555 seven21“
```

Is there any regular expression that can retrieve such patterns from a text？

Also for example: I need to find all rows in my df that have similar pattern - mismatched digits and written numbers.

I tried

```
re.compile(r'\b(?:(?: 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|)(?: +|$)){1,}')
```

I do not have much experience working with regular expressions and it must me something more complicated than that

Comment: Well, for starters, `1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|` would be `\d` (and probably `\d+` for multiple consecutive digits). You're missing `0` in that list, I think.

Comment: make a dictionary with plain text number and decimal ones

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` with the callback parameter: it takes as argument a match object which group will be the key of the dictionary *plain number-digit*.

```
import re


mapper_plain2digit = {'zero': '0', 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3',
'four': '4', 'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8', 'nine': '9'}

phone_nr_regex = rf"({'|'.join(mapper_plain2digit)})"
pattern = re.compile(phone_nr_regex)

phone_nrs = "+89 one5zero 77three3", "+eight2three 555"

for p_nr in phone_nrs:
    p_nr_validated = pattern.sub(lambda m: mapper_plain2digit[m.group(1)], p_nr)
    print(p_nr, p_nr_validated, sep='\n')
```

Output

```
+89 one5zero 77three3
+89 150 7733
+eight2three 555 seven21
+823 555 721
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I learnet a lot from your code!